# How to update parent `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` after child node become smaller?

Tags: css

I have a **parent** `div` with `height: 120px; width: 120px` and a **red child** `div` with `height: 200px; width: 200px`. Now because child node is bigger so it stretch up the `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` of the parent node, and thus **the scrollbar shows**.

[image]

Then I add `transform: scale(0.5)` to the red child `div` to make it smaller, **the vertical scrollbar still shows and `scrollHeight` stays unchanged**, while horizontal scrollbar disappears and `scrollWidth` changes.

[image]

My question is: is there a way to **automatically hide/show all scrollbars after shrinking/expanding the child node**?
In other words, is there a way to **update both `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` according to child node size**?

codesandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/scrollwidth-test-bk04o

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your goal but I think you can calculate your inner div height and width with your scale

```
   **Line 17**

   <div
      style={{
        width: 200 * scale,
        height: 200 * scale,
        background: "red",
        transform: `scale(${scale})`,
        transformOrigin: "0 0"
      }}
    />
```

Comment: I don't want to change the size of the child div, I just want to zoom it. In this demo it is just a red square, but actually it has contents. I want the scrollbar to disappear after shrinking the child div.

Comment: Your outer div change overflow when the inner element width/height changed, it means when you have an element with 200px width, we have overflow and scrollbar and when we have 119px we don\t have it when you want to zoom in or zoom out or something like this, you should change the width and height of the inner component, actually scrollbar depends on width/height of the inner elements